# error at interactive python console

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple class created with the editor pycharm . I want to initiate several objects with different input in the ipython console and check how different objects of the class type behaves. Is it even possible to do it in the console ? I am ending up with the following error:

```
rect = Rectangle(5,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-
   packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
   exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-14-48f6e104f766>", line 1, in <module>
   rect = Rectangle(5,4)
NameError: name 'Rectangle' is not defined
```

I must have missed something in the process.

--------EDIT------------------

I tried the the very same thing at Spyder editor without importing anything there and it works fine there.

Did you mean -
    import Rectangle

I tried it as well and then I got the following error:

```
import Rectangle
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist -
      packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
   File "<ipython-input-15-6878d2e924f4>", line 1, in <module>
import Rectangle
   File "/home/sajjad/Hämtningar/programvara/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2017.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
   module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
   ImportError: No module named Rectangle
```

---------EDIT1------------------

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
/home/sajjad/PycharmProjects/PyQt/book/chap03
```

And the Rectangle.py is within the above directory.

Comment: Did you import your class before doing anything with it in the console? If yes, add that line to the beginning of your code.

Comment: Check the working directory in pycharm - `import os;print os.getcwd()` - is it where Rectangle is?

Comment: `Rectangle` is defined in some file. That's what you import. Suppose its in `rectangle.py`. Then its `import rectangle` and `rect = rectangle.Rectangle(5, 4)`.

Comment: Note that you can't import module located somewhere else current directory (except for modules installed to Python with pip or easy_install). Your phrase "Rectangle.py is within the above directory" made me say that.

Comment: As mentioned in the 2nd EDIT, the module is located in the same directory where python console is running.